# Cross-submission robots.txt for multiple domains on single host

Tags: iis-7, robots.txt, sitemap

We are running a site with multiple languages hosted in a single environment on IIS7.  For example,

- oursite.com  - english
- oursite.de  - german
- oursite.es - spanish

This is a single-host environment.  All of these sites are in the same application space on the same physical machine.

I need to do cross-submission of sitemaps via robots.txt.  Looking at the sitemap.org guidelines for this suggest this is possible, but the [example](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/02/cross-submissions-via-robotstxt-on.html) indicates different physical machines.

Will the following entries in oursite.com/robots.txt work?

```
http://www.oursite.com/sitemap-oursite-de.xml
http://www.oursite.com/sitemap-oursite-es.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll work this way (my guess is it won't), but I think your best bet here is to use some sort of rewrite rule to identify which domain the site is running on and display the appropriate robots.txt for it.